# Can I carry paddy door thoran in international check-in baggage for Canada?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada

I want to take the paddy ( ) door thoran in international check-in baggage for Canada. Please confirm me on that

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What has your own research revealed so far? Eg [What can you bring to Canada](https://travel.gc.ca/returning/customs/what-you-can-bring-home-to-canada) explains the customs declaration process and gives information on restricted and prohibited goods

Comment: It is rare for regulations to mention a specific item, rather it is categories like "food" or "medication". Without any explanations or links relating to them item you want to bring and what categories it might be in, nobody can help you. Please edit your question to explain what this item is.

Comment: I am talking about a decoration, made from plant product, rice stems, with all the seeds/rice grains still in the husk and attached.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the images a Google search revealed:

[image: Source: https://www.amazon.in/Paddy-Rice-toran-Pooja-Length/dp/B09JWP1GDY]
[image: Source: https://www.amazon.in/Paddy-Rice-toran-Pooja-Length/dp/B09JWP1GDY]

You're talking about a decoration, made from plant product, rice stems, with all the seeds/rice grains still in the husk and attached.

---

The page [Bringing food, plant and animal products into Canada](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/services/fpa-apa/bringing-apporter-fpa-eng.html)
suggests:

> Restrictions on what items you are allowed to bring into Canada depend on the product, country of origin and province of import. These controls are set up to help keep Canada's animals, plants and natural habitats healthy and safe. Restrictions may be adjusted at any time due to emerging threats.

That directs you to the [Automated Import Reference System (AIRS)](https://inspection.canada.ca/importing-food-plants-or-animals/food-imports/airs/eng/1300127512994/1326599324773) which seems to categorise the product as:

HS Description : 100610
10  Cereals
06  Rice
10  Rice in the husk (paddy or rough)

but requires more information about the source of the material before it will give you a recommendation.

Comment: seeds is going to be a "no"